# Uncover schema in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, uncover

I'm new to Latex. I need to replicate this figure using Tikz. I plan to place this in a beamer slide and uncover the rectangles one click after another. Could someone please help me figure this out?[image]

Note that B & C here should appear together. Thank you!

Comment: to uncover tikz pictures, I suggest https://ctan.org/pkg/aobs-tikz?lang=en

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with @samcarter, but since you are saying you are new it might be easier to go through the aobs-tikz manual after you have familiarized with the most basic things. All you need here is `\pause` inside some very simple picture.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{mybox/.style={draw,minimum width=1.5cm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Boxes popping up}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{8cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[mybox](A){A};
\pause
\node[mybox,above right=of A](B){B};
\node[mybox,below right=of A](C){C};
\draw[-latex] (A.east)--(B.west);
\draw[-latex] (A.east)--(C.west);
\pause
\node[mybox,below right=of B](D){D};
\draw[-latex] (B.east)--(D.west);
\draw[-latex] (C.east)--(D.west);
\pause
\node[mybox,right=of D](E){E};
\draw[-latex] (D.east)--(E.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]